# Non Blocking ServerSocketChannel

Tags: java, server, nio, nonblocking

```
SocketChannel socketChannel = serverSocketChannel.accept();
```

When a Non-Blocking ServerSocketChannel returns a SocketChannel, after calling `socketChannel.configureBlocking(false)`, is it required to then register the SocketChannel using `socketChannel.register(selector,SelectionKey.OP_CONNECT,new ConnectionHandler)`?

I would assume that once the new SocketChannel has been returned that it is already connected to the remote endpoint and `socketChannel.isConnectionPending()` will return `false` and `socketChannel.isConnected()` will return `true`.

```
public class ConnectionHandler
{
  public void handleConnect ( SelectionKey key )
  {
    SocketChannel socketChannel = SocketChannel.class.cast ( key.channel() );
    socketChannel.finishConnect ();

    socketChannel.register ( key.selector (), SelectionKey.OP_READ );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When a Non-Blocking `ServerSocketChannel` returns a `SocketChannel,` after calling `socketChannel.configureBlocking(false),` is it required to then register the `SocketChannel` using `socketChannel.register(selector,SelectionKey.OP_CONNECT,new ConnectionHandler)`?

No. It's already connected. OP_CONNECT is for clients.

> I would assume that once the new `SocketChannel` has been returned that it is already connected to the remote endpoint and `socketChannel.isConnectionPending()` will return false and `socketChannel.isConnected()` will return true.

Correct.